# A short story perhaps not by Lem

Tags: short-stories, stanislaw-lem

There is a short story, allegedly by Stanisław Lem, **The extraordinary hotel or the thousand and first journey of Ion the Quiet**, appearing in *Imaginary Numbers*, edited by *W. Frucht* (Wiley, 1999), but I can't find it in Lem's bibliographies or websites about him.
I don't have access to the collection itself, so I can't ascertain whether it gives more detail. In [this forum](http://forum.lem.pl/index.php?topic=140.0) some people suggest it might not be actually by Lem.
Does anyone know more? The original title if it is by Lem, the author if it isn't, any story behind it?

Comment: The "arguments" on that thread are the very definition of "weak".

Comment: I can't find it in the list of Lem stories in the ISFDB, but that doesn't mean it's not his. The title is similar to the style  of Lem's Ijon Tichy stories ("The XXXth Voyage/Journey") but is just different enough to be a homage. It could also be an alternate translation, though, which will make searching for an exact title difficult.
http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?166136

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Googling the title it gave me a short story by [**Naum Vilenkin**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naum_Vilenkin). 
Maybe this is the story you're looking for, because Naum Vilenkin was a mathematician and the Book *Imaginary Numbers* treats mathematical stories.

It appears to be in "In Search for Infinity" as found [here](http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/~matc/Readers/HowManyAngels/SearchInfinity.html) and the whole document [here](http://de.scribd.com/doc/103223841/0817638199-Infinity) ( the story starts on page 47 ).

Comment: Yes, that's it! Apparently, when the short story was later included in the /Imaginary Numbers/ anthology, someone misattributed it.

Comment: I have written a post (in Italian) in my blog, in which I do my best to reconstruct how the misunderstanding occurred: http://pignuoli.blogspot.it/2013/02/un-apocrifo-di-lem.html  
Essentially, in the first English translation the following sentence occur:
“Such hotels can be found in the stories about the interstellar traveler Ion the Quiet, the famous hero of ‘The Interstellar Milkman, Ion the Quiet,’ written by the Polish fantasist Stanislaw Lem. Let's hear what he has to say,” and this led subsequent authors to believe that the story was by Lem.

Comment: Yes, DaG is right regarding the beginning sentence in the first translation; he quotes it just as I remember it when I first read it in 1969 in the English translation of Vilenkin's Stories About Sets, and it seemed clear in that context that Vilenkin, not Lem had penned it.